# criar um alerta na hora que aperta botão de soma javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Tenho 3 input text e 1 input button que e o botão que clica em soma então queria criar uma alerta na hora os input text tiver vazio queria mostra-se um alerta dizendo q os campos ta vazio.

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  somatotal();
});

function somatotal() {
  var soma1Val = parseInt(soma1.value);
  var soma2Val = parseInt(soma2.value);

  var soma = soma1Val + soma2Val;
  document.getElementById('resultado').value = soma;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="container">
    <form>
      <input type="text" id="soma1" placeholder="valor 1" required onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" step="0.01" min="0" max="10">
      <input type="text" id="soma2" placeholder="valor 2" required onkeypress="return event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57" min="0.01" step="0.01" min="0" max="10">
      <input id="btn" type="button" value="Somar">
      <input input type="text" id="resultado" placeholder="resultado" readonly>
    </form>
  </div>

</body>
```

Comment: não está definindo a variável `btn`, como ela vai funcionar? não falta ai um `var btn=document.getElementbyId("resultado");`?

Comment: pior q não esta aqui 'var soma = soma1Val + soma2Val; document.getElementById('resultado').value = soma; }' o botão esta funcionando tudo certinho so queria criar um alerta dos input vazio

Comment: então precisa por o código completo Alan, na sua pergunta tem `btn.addEventListener(` sendo que a variável `btn` não foi definida, e nem nesse exemplo que está no seu comentário. Sugiro ver o log da ferramenta do browser (F12) se não tem erros.

Answer (score 1):

Tenta fazer um `if` que verifique que os campos estão preenchidos antes de executar a função, por exemplo:

```js
function somar() {
  let valor1 = document.querySelector("#valor1").value;
  let valor2 = document.querySelector("#valor2").value;

  if(valor1 == '' || valor2 == '') {
    alert('Informe os campos obrigatórios');
  } else {
    let soma = parseInt(valor1) + parseInt(valor2);
    alert(soma);
  }
}
```

```css
input,button {
  margin: 5px 0;
  width: 200px;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<input id="valor1">
<input id="valor2">
<button onclick="somar()">Somar</button>
```